# Assigning New id with PHP end() function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have Database table of Questions. I use the integer variable Id to sort all the elements of the table.

**What do I want?**
Whenever, a new question is added. It is assigned a new id, which is 1 greated than the ID of the last question in my database.

Here is what I do:

```
include('dbconnect.php');



    $ids = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY id ASC');
    $ids->execute(array());
    $result = $ids->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $new_id = end($result['id']); //Error in this line.
    $new_id = $new_id + 1;
```

But, I always get the error

```
Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/question/submit.php on line 20
```

I am using the `FetchAll` statement so I feel, that an array should be returned. Can anyone figure out where is the error.

Each New Question, which is added to the database gets an ID of 1.

Comment: Why don't you use auto increment in your database instead?

Comment: If you can't modify your sql schema easily, you can also do `SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS new_id FROM question`. Your current problem is that `end($array)` gives you the last element of your array, and your giving NULL actually ($result['id']) does not exist). You can use `end($result)['id']` instead (>= php 5.4)

Comment: @Ninsuo Where do u put the semi-colon if I use `end($result)['id']`. Because it does not work if I do `end($result)['id']` or `end($result);['id']`. Please give me a working echo statement using the end function in above style.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. First I need to return the array into some variable like `$list = end($result)` and then use `$list['id']`. This works like a charm. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: I strongly advise against @Ninsuo's approach: it isn't thread-safe.  If two questions are inserted (perhaps by different users) at the same time, a race hazard could emerge whereby both sessions derive the same id for their respective new questions.  Utilising table locks, such as MySQL does behind-the-scenes with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, is the only safe way to perform this operation.

Comment: I agree with you @eggyal, never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [Using `AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> The `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>      id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>      name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
>     ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
>     ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
>
> SELECT * FROM animals;
> ```
>
> Which returns:
>
> ```
> +----+---------+
> | id | name    |
> +----+---------+
> |  1 | dog     |
> |  2 | cat     |
> |  3 | penguin |
> |  4 | lax     |
> |  5 | whale   |
> |  6 | ostrich |
> +----+---------+
> ```
>
> No value was specified for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign `NULL` or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.